# Independent Double picker

Tags: iphone, double, picker

I have double picker one picker for suit (heart, diamond etc) of a card and the other the value of the card (king, ten, two etc). What I want to know how do I eliminate a value from the card picker once it was already selected so it cant be chosen again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your UIPickerView's data stored in an `NSMutableArray`. Then, when the user makes his choices, remove those objects from the data source array, and call

```
[self.myPickerView reloadAllComponents];
```

This will only work, of course, if you're not hardcoding the value for `numberOfRowsInComponent:`, but doing something like

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [dataArray count];
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how that helps?

Comment: ah, apologies, I thought you were trying to reset the pickerView. hold tight, I'll edit.

Comment: Awesome. Do you mind hitting the check by the answer, if this helped?